# Virtual Directory and ASP.NET AJAX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have setup a virtual directory in one of my websites but the updatepanels are not taking effect, they are still reposting the whole page. The problem seems to be the virtual directory because I tried setting it up as a website instead and the updatepanels worked... but when I set it back as a virtual directory they do not work anymore.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Isabelle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/12/10/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax.aspx

Its a known problem that will cause AJAX to not work.

Comment: Wow, this was indeed the problem...

Thanks a million for the help and the quick answer.
You're the best! :-)

Comment: Not to lobby for an upvote, but along with accepting an answer you can show that you like it by voting it up. :-D Welcome to StackOverFlow